# Accessing database on server using android studio

Tags: android, database

I'm a complete beginner in android programming and am trying to make an app which requires access to the database on local host using the android studio, using the IP address of the server, I've watched many tutorial videos but still am not sure where to pass the IP address of the server.
The server uses MySQL, I've tried using JDBC but still unable to achieve the result.

Here is my code, any help would be appreciated.

```
`package com.example.vishal.connectiontest;
import java.sql.*;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.R.attr.name;
import static com.example.vishal.connectiontest.DemoClass.main;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button B1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        final TextView e1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HelloWorld);

        B1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    String result = main();
                    e1.setText(result.toString());
                }
                catch(java.lang.Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Exception");

                }




            }

        });

    }
}

class DemoClass
{

    public static String main()throws Exception
    {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://125.10.10.214/demo" ;
        String uname = "root";
        String pass = "";
        String ip = "";
        String query = "Select UserName from user_info where Id = '90000515'";

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname,pass);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        rs.next();
        String name = rs.getString("UserName");
        return (name);




    }

}`
```

Comment: have a look http://sampleprogramz.com/android/mysqldb.php

Comment: I think that still the best way to do that is using PHP backend between your Android app and MySQL DB, and not connecting directly.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way of integrating Database to your Android Application is using Firebase.
It's really easy to use and other than Database, it has File Storage Services, Cloud Messaging, Analytics and many more.
I would recommend use of firebase database.
Here have a look at it's Documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/